# Zeppelin Apache - Add Download button using angular so as to download Pandas or PySpark Dataframe

Tags: angularjs, csv, button, download, apache-zeppelin

I am currently using Apache Zeppelin and i have a pandas/pyspark dataframe and i would like to give the option to the end user to download it as a csv file (or any excel related format).

To do that i need to use AngularJS language but i don't know how to write the necessary code which will take the data-frame and download it as an excel table.

What i have done so far is the following:

- I got the pandas dataframe and converted it to JSON String (csv_table_output). Image below

[image]

- Then i found the following angular code online which i would like to use to export the table as a CSV format:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/815fb404daa94979596db7731934d5bd

stockData55 is the variable where i want to put the output string from csv_table_output. When i use the string as it is it works ok but i dont know how to parse the info from csv_table_output to angular variable

If there is a better way to do that instead of using the attached code im happy to see that

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin v0.6.0 includes [ZEPPELIN-997](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-997), allowing you to export dataframes as csv or tsv natively, e.g.:

```
%pyspark 

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')], 
                                ('id', 'name'))

z.show(df)
```

which renders as:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this button is available when you are on development mode. When you go to the report mode (report that you will share with other users) then all these buttons are not available

Comment: This output is controlled by ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_OUTPUT_LIMIT which can't be set at the user level.